# apache 2.4 doesn't work one of two virtual hosts

Tags: php, apache, web, admin, backend

I have two vhosts `test.com` and `example.com` on one machine. The `test.com` woks fine, but `example.com` server redirect to world wide web. Configuration other vhosts indentical, code too. Syntax or semantics errors are not found. Apache works fine. No messages in `error.log`. I don't understand why one vhost works and second vhost didn't. Files `test.com.conf` and `example.com.conf` from `/etc/apache2/sites-available`:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot /var/www/test.com/public_html
ServerName test.com
ServerAlias www.test.com
ServerAdmin anymail@gmail.com

ErrorLog /var/www/test.com/log/error.log
CustomLog /var/www/test.com/log/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
########################################################################
<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot /var/www/example.com/public_html
ServerName example.com
ServerAlias www.example.com
ServerAdmin anymail@yahoo.com

ErrorLog /var/www/example.com/log/error.log
CustomLog /var/www/example.com/log/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

`apache2.conf`:

```
DefaultRuntimeDir ${APACHE_RUN_DIR}
PidFile ${APACHE_PID_FILE}
Timeout 300
KeepAlive On
MaxKeepAliveRequests 100
KeepAliveTimeout 5
User ${APACHE_RUN_USER}
Group ${APACHE_RUN_GROUP}
HostnameLookups Off
ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
LogLevel warn
IncludeOptional mods-enabled/*.load
IncludeOptional mods-enabled/*.conf
Include ports.conf
<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Require all denied
</Directory>
<Directory /usr/share>
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Directory>
<Directory /var/www/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Directory>
AccessFileName .htaccess

<FilesMatch "^\.ht">
    Require all denied
</FilesMatch>

<FilesMatch "\.php$">
    SetHandler application/x-httpd-php
</FilesMatch>

<FilesMatch "^\.phps$">
    SetHandler application/x-httpd-php-source
</FilesMatch>
LogFormat "%v:%p %h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" vhost_combined
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" combined
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O" common
LogFormat "%{Referer}i -> %U" referer
LogFormat "%{User-agent}i" agent

IncludeOptional conf-enabled/*.conf

IncludeOptional sites-enabled/*.conf
```

`/etc/hosts`:

```
127.0.0.1   test.com
127.0.0.1   example.com
127.0.0.1   localhost
```

`diff` from `/test.com/.../index.php` and `example.com/.../index.php`

```
9c9
<       echo "Welcome to example.com";
---
>       echo "Welcome to test.com";
```

@elitepc @akshaypjoski Yes, I was used `a2ensite` tool and always restart server after changing it cofig files.

@DrCord  , @Nix3500 the problem now looks another. I will made sure the server works fine. I type `nmap -A example.com` and had seen `127.0.0.1` on output. After this I typed standard shell perl GET script and got my html page on output. But! The web browsers (Mozilla, Chromium) give me page `example.com` from `93.184.216.34` ip address. I was a trifle embarrassed.

In conclusion I have now next: from shell no problem; from web browsers `test.com` works fine and `example.com` i get from `93.184.216.34` domain.

Comment: I hate to ask this but, did you already restart apache? And if you delete the example.com part (if not in production), does it keep working? After deleting it does test.com start working?

Comment: Did you try reversing the order of the hosts in the `VirtualHost` declaration? I would bet that it is that the first one is working and then the second one is not and if you reverse the declaration order then `example.com` will work and `test.com` will not.

Comment: Have you enabled your both sites using `a2ensite` command?

Comment: Change your `LogLevel debug` and run again, it might provide something.  And what does "...server redirect to world wide web" mean?  There is no redirection in the posted configuration.  You have a redirect in your PHP file?  Other thing to try, replace `IncludeOptional` by `Include`, so any error at the include level will be displayed.

Comment: I have edit post. See last three paragraph.

Comment: Now I install Gnome Web Browser and try it. Vhosts works fine. Where is problem? Why firefox and chromium ignore local server?